# update column name in excel file in c#

Tags: c#, excel, sql-update

I have a excel file with columns as below:

No.  | Index  |  Module  | OriKey

When I import data from this excel file, the No. column will cause error. Hence, I plan to change the No. column name to No before I import the data. But it causes the same error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [" + listTable[1] + "] SET [No.] = 'No'", excelConnection))
{
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

So is there any mthod to update the Column name.And I have set the Extended Properties=\'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2\'", so I cannot use the column number to get the data